# In which module does the Timer class reside in python?

Tags: python, timer

Am reading the following online [Timer](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/timer-objects.html) manual for python 2.5, but am wondering where is the actual module where the class Timer resides?

Gath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to figure this out: on the page you linked to, there's an Up link.  It goes to the threading module.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the `threading` module.